# Flutter inspector Crashes when toggle to IOS

Tags: dart, flutter, inspector

I just started learning Flutter so I started a new project, didn't edit it at all. When running the app using the android emulator, everything looks fine, but when I toggle to IOS from Flutter Inspector I get this error

> 'package: flutter/src/renering/object.dart': Failed Assertion: line 1152 pos12: 'child.parentData !=null': is not true.

Any idea why this is happening? 
[image]

Comment: could you update the answer with some parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16560
There is no solution or workaround available yet.
Please upvote the initial comment in the issue to raise priority.